# Qgis extremely slow on averything

Tags: qgis

My Qgis is behaving terribly slow the last few months. Opening takes minutes, trying to switch between the layers panel and the browser panel takes minutes, selecting an arcgis featurelayer takes minutes, trying to add data takes minutes, closing takes minutes. Pretty much everything takes a long, long time.

I tried removing Qgis and all asociated files and re-installing it, but no luck. I tried a fresh profile: no luck.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, especially with switching between Layers and Browser panel. I solved this with acitivating *Fast Scan this directory* option from the context menu in the Browser panel for all the hard drives I'm using.

[image: Fast scan optin QGIS]